# How can I increase spawn rate of mining armor/undead miner?

Tags: terraria

I'm having trouble with finding the mining armor set dropped from the undead miner.
[image: undead miner]<---- This guy

The **pants** and **shirt** have a 2.4% dropping rate.
I already bought the **helmet** from the merchant.

### What have I tried?

I have explored the underground for an hour with battle potions on but I have encountered the undead miner 2 times now. I think this could be faster.

### Question

How can I increase spawn rate of mining armor/undead miner?

I'm looking for a good:

- Farming method
- AFK method

### Trophy

I need this set for the:

[image: A Knight in Shining Armors]
*A Knight in Shining Armors*

*Note: I'm playing the console version.*

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I'm not sure the spawn rate of any one enemy can be affected with any reliability. Like so much of Terraria, I think it's mostly just left to chance. Battle potions and blue candles may help in general.

Comment: Does the console version have blue candles? Those stack with Battle Potions I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Yes we have! Thank you both for the comments. Haven't thought about bringing candles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion for increasing the number of miners you encounter is to simply increase the number of total monsters you encounter. Try using the following:

1. create 1 large open cavern underground. This increases the likelihood they will spawn in an area where they can run to you. If you do not do this, there is a good chance they will spawn in a pocket not reachable to you (they still count as being spawned on screen and will reduce the amount of enemies you find).
2. If you can, play multi-player. The spawn rate and maximum number of enemies allowed on screen is directly proportional to the number of players.
3. Use battle potions. These increase the number of monsters that will spawn
4. use Water candles. Place them around your large cavern. Being close to them will increase the spawn rate of monsters. You can also hold 1 in your hand, this will futher increase the number of enemies that spawn.

Comment: If there is a candle on the ground or somewhere nearby and one in your hand, do those candles stack their effects?

Comment: Yes. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_Candle

Comment: Be aware that even with all of these techniques being used, Undead Miners are rare enemies and it could take a long time to finish the clothing set depending on how lucky you are.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have found 2 shirts with this method :) I'm going back for my pants now!